# Implementing Authentication with external provider (e.g. Twitch)

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, access-token, twitch, stateless

I'm developing a web application consiting of two parts: a **Flask REST API** as a backend and a **React.js SPA** as a frontend.

Now I'm at the stage of implementing **authentication via an external provider** (Twitch in particular). I'm not quite sure how I should handle these `access/refresh/id` tokens returned by Twitch, what am I supposed to return to the frontend from my backend or how they supposed to interract with each other?

For now I've done these:

- "Login" button at my frontend side which sends user to Twitch's login form
- Twitch then redirects the request to my backend route (e.g. `/auth/callback/twitch`)
- This route receives `code` query param and tries to exchange it with Twitch for `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `id_token`
- and after that this route returns a redirect response to `/home` page of the application with `id_token` set in cookies

The thing is that I'm not sure it's exactly what I need. Still got some blind spots on this matter:

- Should I use the `id_token` provided by Twitch to identify the User or should I generate my own JWT token with some User's data?
- Where should I persist that `id_token` (considering I tend to stateless design of the app and I want to be able to call my API directly just providing the valid credentials)?

  - probably for Users flow it's enough to use cookies?
  - and for direct access to my API there should be another way of auth (e.g. with `Bearer token`)?
- Should I take care of a freshness of the `id_token` (considering I only need it to authenticate the User inside my system)
- Am I right that I don't need the pair of `access_token` and `refresh_token` received from Twitch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.